# Issue with QDockwidget. Gets squeezed to minimum with only buttons visible

Tags: qt, qt5

I create a **QDockWidge**t and I do a setwidget with my own **QMenu** instance. My `QMenu` has n number of `QActions` displayed sequentially one after another and there is a blank space at the end of all action items. Now, when I click on this blank space, my `QDockwidget` minimizes to an icon. Just the close and detach buttons are visible. Any reason for this strange behaviour?

The code looks something like this :

```
QDockWidget *dw = new QDockWidget(this);

QMenu * menu = new QMenu(this)

menu->addAction(1);

menu->addAction(2);
.
.
dw->setWidget(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue of OP. In absence of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I made my own `testQDockWidgetMenu.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup UI
  QMainWindow qWinMain;
  QLabel qLbl("Choose a menu item");
  qWinMain.setCentralWidget(&qLbl);
  QDockWidget qDock;
  qDock.setWindowTitle("Dockable Menu");
  QMenu qMenu("Menu");
#define ADD_ITEM(I) \
  qMenu.addAction( \
    "Menu Item "#I, [&]() { qLbl.setText("Menu item "#I" chosen."); })
  ADD_ITEM(1);
  ADD_ITEM(2);
  ADD_ITEM(3);
#undef ADD_ITEM
  qDock.setWidget(&qMenu);
  qWinMain.addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, &qDock);
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

A minimal Qt project `testQDockWidgetMenu.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQDockWidgetMenu.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and run in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQDockWidgetMenu.pro

$ make && ./testQDockWidgetMenu
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQDockWidgetMenu.o testQDockWidgetMenu.cc
g++  -o testQDockWidgetMenu.exe testQDockWidgetMenu.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: snapshot (start)] [image: snapshot (item clicked)]

After I clicked into the blank space on the right I got this (like described by OP):

[image: snapshot (after clicking into blank space)]

Oops! (I hadn't expected this.)

I believe this behavior is built-in into menus: As they are intended for popup-menus there is an auto-close when an out-side click is detected.

I scrolled a bit through the doc. of [`QMenu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html) whether there is something to suppress this default behavior. Instead, I found:

> #### [void QMenu::aboutToHide()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToHide)
>
> This signal is emitted just before the menu is hidden from the user.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 4.2.

This is, at least, good for a workaround: If the auto-close intends to hide the menu just show it again. To check this, I added a signal handler:

```
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qMenu, &QMenu::aboutToHide,
    [&]{
      QWidget *const pQParent = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(qMenu.parent());
      if (pQParent && pQParent->isVisible()) {
        qMenu.show();
        qDebug() << "Prevent hiding qMenu";
      }
    });
```

(inserted just above `return app.exec();`)

Compiled and run again: Et voilà. No auto-close anymore.

[image: snapshot (after clicking multiple times into blank space)]

The debug output in console shows that the signal handler does what it is intended for:

```
Qt Version: 5.9.4
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
Prevent hiding qMenu
```

**Note:**

The check for `if (pQParent && pQParent->isVisible())` could appear a bit paranoid and might be unnecessary.

I tried without and it worked as well. Though, I noted that the debug message appeared also e.g. when I closed the whole dock. Not that this changed the visual appearance – if a parent widget is invisible the children are as well.

So, I came to the conclusion that the paranoid check doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually after circling around, I choose to use QToolbar instead of QMenu which solved the probem